# Problems with parallel for loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to load a full auctionhouse by loading each page async from an api call and putting all the same items together in a list in a dictionary. When I make the parallel for loop, It does not return anything. Help would be appricieted.

Have a great day!
-Vexea

```
    {
        string url = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions";

        //Gets number of pages to make threads on the auction house...
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.GetApiClient("application/json").GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                AuctionHouseModel auctionHouse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuctionHouseModel>();
                return auctionHouse.Pages;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task<AuctionPageModel> LoadHypixelAuctionPage(int page, string apiKey)
    {
        //Loads a solid page...
        string url = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=" + apiKey + "&page=" + page;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.GetApiClient("application/json").GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuctionPageModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public async static Task<AuctionHouseModel> LoadHypixelAuctionHouse(string apiKey)
    {
        //Loads all pages needed and puts them into a dictionary...
        List<AuctionPageModel> pages = new List<AuctionPageModel>();
        AuctionHouseModel output = new AuctionHouseModel();

        Parallel.For(1, await LoadHypixelAuctionPages(), async page => {
            pages.Add(await LoadHypixelAuctionPage(page, apiKey)); //This returns nothing, count of pages stays 0 and nothing happens...
        });

        foreach (AuctionPageModel page in pages)
            foreach(AuctionProductModel product in page.Products)
                try
                {
                    output.Products[product.Name].Add(product);
                }
                catch
                {
                    output.Products.Add(product.Name, new List<AuctionProductModel>());
                    output.Products[product.Name].Add(product);
                }
        output.Pages = await LoadHypixelAuctionPages();
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing parallel programming you need to make sure to use thread-safe types or locking. Perhaps there're more things wrong than this, but the first thing you need to fix is making sure to lock access to the `pages` list. Secondly, the first paramenter in [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Action_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState__) is **inclusive** while the second parameter is **exclusive**. So if `LoadHypixelAuctionPages()` returns 0 or 1, nothing will run inside the loop, so you probably mean `LoadHypixelAuctionPages() + 1` if the first page number is 1 and not 0:

```
List<AuctionPageModel> pages = new List<AuctionPageModel>();
AuctionHouseModel output = new AuctionHouseModel();

Parallel.For(1, await LoadHypixelAuctionPages() + 1, async page =>
{
    var loadedPage = await LoadHypixelAuctionPage(page, apiKey);
    lock(pages)
    {
        pages.Add(loadedPage);
    }
});

//...
```

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Action_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState__) to see what can happen when not locking.

An alternative to locking is using one of the [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0), such as [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any `Parallel` methods with `async`. Parallel is for CPU-bound code and `async` is (primarily) for I/O-bound code. The `Parallel` class doesn't properly understand anything `async`.

Instead of parallel concurrency, you need asynchronous concurrency (`Task.WhenAll`):

```
List<AuctionPageModel> pages = new List<AuctionPageModel>();
AuctionHouseModel output = new AuctionHouseModel();

var tasks = Enumerable
    .Range(1, await LoadHypixelAuctionPages())
    .Select(async page => pages.Add(await LoadHypixelAuctionPage(page, apiKey)))
    .ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

or, more simply:

```
AuctionHouseModel output = new AuctionHouseModel();

var tasks = Enumerable
    .Range(1, await LoadHypixelAuctionPages())
    .Select(async page => await LoadHypixelAuctionPage(page, apiKey))
    .ToList();
var pages = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you! i will look into it right now.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. If you see this comment could you explain were I can find information on this syntax. I am a new programming and I would like to also use this syntax.

Comment: @Vexea: This is a combination of `async`/`await` with LINQ.